# How to get driver version by Hardware ID?

Tags: c#, c++, powershell, windows-8.1

I'm trying to get the all drivers version show in device manager by Hardware ID. And first I tried is to use Powershell to show the version list.

```
gwmi Win32_SystemDriver | select name,@{n="version";e={(gi $_.pathname).VersionInfo.FileVersion}}
```

but it seems not all the drivers in the computer and I still cannot know the HWID.
Then I tried the wmi win32_pnpsigneddriver. But it return only pnp driver.
I think the closest way is to use setupapi.h

```
SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail()
```

but after trying it always returns an error "No more data is available.".

could anyone gives me any example or correct way to find it?
Thanks a lot!